# Stipe, how to pay an invoice from front (by receiving clientSecret from backend), using an saved payment method?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, payment

Stipe, how to pay an invoice from front end (by receiving client secret from backend, or from paymentIntentId), using an saved payment method?

```
      const finalizedInvoize = await this.stripeService.finalizeInvoice(invoice.id);

      const paymentIntent = await this.stripeService.getPaymentIntent(finalizedInvoize.payment_intent.toString());

      return { clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret }
```

When i finalize my invoice i get the payment intent from it and i get the clientSecret and send it to front end to finish payment.
The problem i want to solve it is how to use a saved payment method and with that payment method to complete the transaction?  
I want to use a saved payment method and not enter new card information to pay for that. 
Can i use: https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment

Answer (score 0):

To use the saved payment method on an Invoice, the payment method ID can be set in [`default_payment_method`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/create#create_invoice-default_payment_method) parameter of the Invoice creation request.

Comment: When i set the default payment method ( in create invoice ), is the invoice charged automatically or should i confirm it again in front end ?